# Using a singular and plural in the same sentence

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, parallelism

> During fourth grade, a group of **pupils** picked on **me** frequently.

I have pupils and me in the same sentence. I was wondering if this is legal or do I need to change me to a plural word.

- Thank you in advance.

Comment: How could there be a plural form of 'me'? How many people are you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem in general with mixing singular and plural in the same sentence. The only requirement is that the subject and verb need to agree. But a singular subject can take action on plural objects:

> I ate three apples.

and plural subjects can act on singular objects:

> The students listened to the teacher.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the sentence 'During fourth grade, a group of pupils picked on me frequently.' is correct.

There is no accepted plural of 'me'. The word 'me' is a pronoun that refers back to the person who is speaking.

Answer (score 0):

This is fine as is.  In fact, the object of the sentence, "group of pupils" would actually be considered singular as it functions as a collective noun.

It would also be correct if the object was truly plural, e.g. "During fourth grade, pupils picked on me frequently."